# Resize image to fullscreen or filesize

Tags: jquery, image-size

I try to load an image as a "lightbox" image on the complete screen.
The image should be resized to the screensize (with 35px space on each side - depending on the bigger side [width/height]) but it shouldn't get bigger than the filesize. How can I do that?

```
$('body').prepend('<div id="overlay" style="display: none;"></div>');
$('#overlay').fadeIn();

$('body').prepend('<div id="content" style="display: none;"><img class="photo" src="images/file.jpg" /></div>');
$(".photo").load(function(){
    var h_image = $(this).height()-70; // I do not get the height of the image... What's wrong?
    var h_screen= $(window).height()-70;
    if (h_image> h_screen) {
        $(this).height(s_screen);
    }
    else {
        $(this).height(h_image);
    }
    $('#content').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the filesize"? Do you mean it can't be bigger in bytes than the original size of the file?

Comment: no, I mean the dimensions. ie: If the image file has the dimensions 3000x2000px, the image will displayed in the screensize ie 1440x900px. But if the dimensions of the image is 400x300px it will be displayed as 400x300px, because it can't be bigger than that.

Comment: OK; you want to preserve the aspect ratio.

Comment: The aspect ratio of the image shouldn't be changed. If the image has 3:2, it should alsways be displayd as 3:2, so in the comment example above the big image would be displayed as 1350x900px. I marked the line in the code which don't give me any height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change [`height()`](https://api.jquery.com/height/) to [`offset().height`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/):

```
$('body').prepend('<div id="overlay" style="display: none;"></div>');
$('#overlay').fadeIn();

$('body').prepend('<div id="content" style="display: none;"><img class="photo" src="images/file.jpg" /></div>');
$(".photo").load(function(){
    var h_image = $(this).offset().height-70;
    var h_screen= $(window).height()-70;
    if (h_image> h_screen) {
        $(this).height(s_screen);
    }
    else {
        $(this).height(h_image);
    }
    $('#content').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: @user3142695 If my answer has helped you, could you up-vote my answer, please?

Comment: What is the difference between this.height and this.offset().height?